# Me marca que es diferente cuando tienen el mismo valor

Tags: java, mvc, eclipse

estoy desarrollando un juego de cartas para una práctica, y para comprobar unos valores entre las cartas de un jugador y otro, no me da el resultado correspondiente, como veis por consola me sale "El jugador 3 ha mentido, su carta era un: 7 y el numero inicial era un 7", cosa que esta mal, ya que especifico en el if que si son iguales, me debería escribir otra cosa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el codigo:

```
public class Controlador implements ActionListener, WindowListener, MouseListener{
VistaMenuPrincipal vistaMenu;
VistaCrearJugador vistaCrearJ;
VistaCrearPartida vistaCrearP;
VistaJugando vistaJugando;
VistaMejoresJ vistaMejoresJ;
Modelo modelo;
Connection conexion = null;
String informacion ="";

int mazoJugador1[] = new int[12];
int mazoJugador2[] = new int[12];
int mazoJugador3[] = new int[12];
int mazoJugador4[] = new int[12];
int mazoDescarte[] = new int [48];
int numeroInicial = 0;
int cartaActual =0;
int cartaActualJugador1 = 0;
int cartaActualJugador2 = 0;
int cartaActualJugador3 = 0;
int cartaActualJugador4 = 0;
int puntosJugador1 = 0;
int puntosJugador2 = 0;
int puntosJugador3 = 0;
int puntosJugador4 = 0;
int turno = 0;
int uno,dos,tres,cuatro;
```

public Controlador(VistaMejoresJ objvistaMej, VistaMenuPrincipal objvistaM, VistaCrearJugador objvistaJ, VistaCrearPartida objvistaP, VistaJugando objvistaJug, Modelo objmodelo)
{

```
    this.vistaMejoresJ = objvistaMej;
    this.vistaMenu = objvistaM;
    this.vistaCrearJ = objvistaJ;
    this.vistaCrearP = objvistaP;
    this.vistaJugando = objvistaJug;
    this.modelo = objmodelo;

    this.vistaMejoresJ.addWindowListener(this);
    this.vistaCrearP.addWindowListener(this);
    this.vistaMenu.addWindowListener(this);
    this.vistaJugando.addWindowListener(this);
    this.vistaJugando.addMouseListener(this);


    //ELEMENTOS VISTA JUGADOR
    objvistaJ.addWindowListener(this);
    objvistaJ.ventanaCrearJugador.addWindowListener(this);
    objvistaJ.dialogoMensajeJugadorCreado.addWindowListener(this);
    objvistaJ.crearJugador.addActionListener(this);
    objvistaJ.cerrarJugador.addActionListener(this);

    //ELEMENTOS VISTA PARTIDA
    objvistaP.addWindowListener(this);
    objvistaP.ventanaCrearPartida.addWindowListener(this);
    objvistaP.dialogoMensajePartidaCreada.addWindowListener(this);
    objvistaP.buttonIniciarPartida.addActionListener(this);
    objvistaP.cerrarPartida.addActionListener(this);

    //ELEMENTOS VISTA MENU
    objvistaM.ventanaMenu.addWindowListener(this);
    objvistaM.buttonCrearPartida.addActionListener(this);
    objvistaM.buttonMenuCrearJugador.addActionListener(this);
    objvistaM.buttoncomoSeJuega.addActionListener(this);
    objvistaM.buttonMejoresJugadores.addActionListener(this);
    objvistaM.buttonSalirMenu.addActionListener(this);

    //ELEMENTOS VISTA JUGANDO
    objvistaJug.ventanaJuego.addWindowListener(this);
    objvistaJug.ventanaJuego.addMouseListener(this);
    objvistaJug.dlgMensaje.addWindowListener(this);

    //ELEMENTOS VISTA GENERAL
    objvistaMej.ventanaMejoresJugadores.addWindowListener(this);
    objvistaMej.cerrar.addActionListener(this);
    objvistaMej.addWindowListener(this);
    objvistaMej.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento) 
{
    //CREAR PARTIDA
    if(vistaMenu.buttonCrearPartida.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        this.vistaCrearP.setVisible(true);
        new VistaCrearPartida();
    }
    //INICIO DE LA PARTIDA
    if(vistaCrearP.buttonIniciarPartida.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {   
        //CONECTAMOS A LA BASE DE DATOS
        conexion = this.modelo.conectar();
        //REALIZAR LA CONSULTA E INSERTAR INFORMACIÓN
        informacion = this.modelo.crearPartidaNueva(conexion);
        //CERRAMOS CONEXION
        this.modelo.cerrar(conexion);
        new VistaJugando();
        this.vistaJugando.setVisible(true);
        this.modelo.barajar(mazoJugador1, mazoJugador2, mazoJugador3, mazoJugador4);
        numeroInicial= this.modelo.numeroInicialSeleccionado(null);

        System.out.println("LAS CARTAS HAN SIDO REPARTIDAS:");
        for(int i= 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Carta jugador1: " + mazoJugador1[i]+"   --    >"+"Carta jugador2: " +mazoJugador2[i]+"   --    >"+"Carta jugador3: " +mazoJugador3[i]+"   --    >"+"Carta jugador4: " +mazoJugador4[i]);

        }           
    }


    //CREAR JUGADOR
    else if(vistaMenu.buttonMenuCrearJugador.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        this.vistaCrearJ.setVisible(true);
        new VistaCrearJugador();

    }

    else if(vistaCrearJ.crearJugador.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {

    }

    //COMO SE JUEGA
    else if(vistaMenu.buttoncomoSeJuega.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        this.modelo.ayuda();
    }

    //CONSULTA MEJORES JUGADORES
    else if(vistaMenu.buttonMejoresJugadores.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        vistaMejoresJ.ventanaMejoresJugadores.setVisible(true);
        //CONECTAMOS A LA BASE DE DATOS
        conexion = this.modelo.conectar();
        //REALIZAR LA CONSULTA E INSERTAR INFORMACIÓN
        informacion = this.modelo.mejoresJugadores(conexion);
        //RELLENAMOS EL TEXTAREA
        this.vistaMejoresJ.listadoJugadores.append(informacion);
        //CERRAMOS CONEXION
        this.modelo.cerrar(conexion);
    }

    //BOTONES QUE CIERRAN VENTANAS
    if(vistaMenu.buttonSalirMenu.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    else if(vistaCrearJ.cerrarJugador.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {

        this.vistaCrearJ.setVisible(false);
    }

    else if(vistaCrearP.cerrarPartida.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        this.vistaCrearP.setVisible(false);

    }

    else if(vistaMejoresJ.cerrar.equals(evento.getSource()))
    {
        this.vistaMejoresJ.ventanaMejoresJugadores.setVisible(false);
    }

}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evento) 
{       
    if(vistaCrearP.isActive())
    {
        this.vistaCrearP.setVisible(false);
    }

    else if(vistaCrearJ.isActive())
    {
        this.vistaCrearJ.setVisible(false);
    }

    else if(vistaJugando.isActive())
    {
        this.vistaJugando.setVisible(false);
    }

    else if(vistaMejoresJ.ventanaMejoresJugadores.isActive())
    {
        this.vistaMejoresJ.ventanaMejoresJugadores.setVisible(false);
    }
}


public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evento)
{       
    int x = evento.getX();
    int y = evento.getY();

    //TURNOS
    //TURNO JUGADOR 1
    if((x>=340)&&(x<=449)&&(y>=65)&&(y<=215)&&(turno==0))//JUGADOR 1 LANZA CARTA
    {   
        this.vistaJugando.mostrarCartaMazo1(mazoJugador1[cartaActualJugador1]);
        cartaActualJugador1++;
        turno = 1;
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 1 HA LANZADO CARTA, TURNO DEL JUGADOR 2.");
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 2 ¿LANZAS O LEVANTAS?");
    }
    
    if((x>=340)&&(x<=449)&&(y>=165)&&(y<=315)&&(turno==0))//JUGADOR 1 LEVANTA LA CARTA DEL JUGADOR 4
    {
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 1 LLAMA MENTIROSO AL JUGADOR 4. LEVANTA SUS CARTAS.");
        if(numeroInicial==mazoJugador4[cartaActualJugador4])
        {
            System.out.println("El jugador 4 no ha mentido, su carta era un:" + mazoJugador4[cartaActualJugador4-1] + "y el numero inicial era un " + numeroInicial);
        }
        else if(numeroInicial!=mazoJugador4[cartaActualJugador4])
        {
            System.out.println("El jugador 4 ha mentido, su carta era un:" + mazoJugador4[cartaActualJugador4-1] + "y el numero inicial era un " + numeroInicial);
        }
        System.out.println("EL JUGADOR 1, SELECCIONA UN NUEVO NUMERO EL:");
        this.modelo.nuevoNumeroSeleccionado(null);
    }


    //TURNO JUGADOR 2
    else if ((x>=340)&&(x<=449)&&(y>=295)&&(y<=445)&&(turno==1))//jUGADOR 2 LANZA CARTA
    {
        this.vistaJugando.mostrarCartaMazo2(mazoJugador2[cartaActualJugador2]);
        cartaActualJugador2++;
        turno = 2;
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 2 HA LANZADO CARTA, TURNO DEL JUGADOR 3.");
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 3 ¿LANZAS O LEVANTAS?");
    } 
    
    if((x>=340)&&(x<=449)&&(y>=165)&&(y<=315)&&(turno==1))//JUGADOR 2 LEVANTA CARTA JUGADOR 1
    {
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 2 LLAMA MENTIROSO AL JUGADOR 1. LEVANTA SUS CARTAS.");
        if(numeroInicial==mazoJugador1[cartaActualJugador1])
        {
            System.out.println("El jugador 1 no ha mentido, su carta era un:" + mazoJugador1[cartaActualJugador1-1] + "y el numero inicial era un " + numeroInicial);
        }
        else if(numeroInicial!=mazoJugador1[cartaActualJugador1])
        {
            System.out.println("El jugador 1 ha mentido, su carta era un:" + mazoJugador1[cartaActualJugador1-1] + "y el numero inicial era un " + numeroInicial);
        }
        System.out.println("EL JUGADOR 2, SELECCIONA UN NUEVO NUMERO EL:");
        this.modelo.nuevoNumeroSeleccionado(null);

    }

    //TURNO JUGADOR 3
    else if((x>=60)&&(x<=169)&&(y>=180)&&(y<=330)&&(turno==2))//JUGADOR 3 LANZA CARTA
    {
        this.vistaJugando.mostrarCartaMazo3(mazoJugador3[cartaActualJugador3]);
        cartaActualJugador3++;
        turno = 3;
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 3 HA LANZADO CARTA, TURNO DEL JUGADOR 4.");
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 4 ¿LANZAS O LEVANTAS?");
    }
    
    //JUGADOR 3 LEVANTA CARTAS DEL JUGADOR 2
    if((x>=340)&&(x<=419)&&(y>=165)&&(y<=315)&&(turno==2))
    {
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 3 LLAMA MENTIROSO AL JUGADOR 2. LEVANTA SUS CARTAS.");
        if(numeroInicial==mazoJugador2[cartaActualJugador2])
        {
            System.out.println("El jugador 2 no ha mentido, su carta era un:" + mazoJugador2[cartaActualJugador2-1] + "y el numero inicial era un " + numeroInicial);
        }
        else if(numeroInicial!=mazoJugador2[cartaActualJugador2])
        {
            System.out.println("El jugador 2 ha mentido, su carta era un:" + mazoJugador2[cartaActualJugador2-1] + "y el numero inicial era un " + numeroInicial);
        }
        System.out.println("EL JUGADOR 3, SELECCIONA UN NUEVO NUMERO EL:");
        this.modelo.nuevoNumeroSeleccionado(null);
    }

    //TURNO JUGADOR 4
    else if((x>=650)&&(x<=759)&&(y>=180)&&(y<=330)&&(turno==3))
    {
        this.vistaJugando.mostrarCartaMazo4(mazoJugador4[cartaActualJugador4]);//MOSTRAR LA CARTA DEL MAZO 4
        cartaActualJugador4++;
        turno =0;
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 4 HA LANZADO CARTA, TURNO DEL JUGADOR 1.");
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 1 ¿LANZAS O LEVANTAS?");
    }
    
    //JUGADOR 4 LEVANTA CARTAS DEL JUGADOR 3
    if((x>=340)&&(x<=449)&&(y>=165)&&(y<=315)&&(turno==3))
    {
        System.out.println("JUGADOR 4 LLAMA MENTIROSO AL JUGADOR 3. LEVANTA SUS CARTAS.");
        if(numeroInicial==mazoJugador3[cartaActualJugador3])
        {
            System.out.println("El jugador 3 no ha mentido, su carta era un:" + mazoJugador3[cartaActualJugador3-1] + "y el numero inicial era un " + numeroInicial);
        }
        else if(numeroInicial!=mazoJugador3[cartaActualJugador3])
        {
            System.out.println("El jugador 3 ha mentido, su carta era un:" + mazoJugador3[cartaActualJugador3-1] + "y el numero inicial era un " + numeroInicial);
        }
        System.out.println("EL JUGADOR 4, SELECCIONA UN NUEVO NUMERO EL:");
        this.modelo.nuevoNumeroSeleccionado(null);
    }


}
```

Comment: Diría que no estás comparando la misma carta. Prueba a cambiarlo por `if(numeroInicial==mazoJugador3[cartaActualJugador3 - 1])` . Lo mismo en todos los `if` donde hagas la comparación.

Comment: ¡Efectivamente!, muchísimas gracias, estaba volviéndome loco y no lograba ver el fallo, estaba en un bloqueo mental muy tonto.